# c# enum exclude

Tags: c#, enums

Let's say I have an enum like this:

```
[Flags]
public enum NotificationMethodType {
    Email = 1,
    Fax = 2,
    Sms = 4
}
```

And let's say I have a variable defined as:

```
NotificationMethodType types = (NotificationMethodType.Email | NotificationMethodType.Fax)
```

How do I figure out all of the NotificationMethodType values that are not defined in the "types" variable? In other words:

```
NotificationMethodType notAssigned = NotificationMethodType <that are not> types
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If the list of types never changes, you can do this:

```
NotificationMethodType allTypes = NotificationMethodType.Email |
    NotificationMethodType.Fax |
    NotificationMethodType.Sms;

NotificationMethodType notAssigned = allTypes & ~types;
```

The ~ creates an inverse value, by inverting all the bits.

A typical way to define such enums to at least keep the definition of "allTypes" local to the enum would be to include two new names into the enum:

```
[Flags]
public enum NotificationMethodType {
    None = 0,
    Email = 1,
    Fax = 2,
    Sms = 4,
    All = Email | Fax | Sms
}
```

**Note**: If you go the route of adding the `All` value to the enum, note that if `types` was empty, you would not get an enum that would *print* as "Email, Fax, Sms", but rather as "All".

If you don't want to manually maintain the list of `allTypes`, you can do it using the `Enum.GetValues` method:

```
NotificationMethodType allTypes = 0;
foreach (NotificationMethodType type in Enum.GetValues(typeof(NotificationMethodType)))
    allTypes |= type;
```

or you can do the same with LINQ:

```
NotificationMethodType allTypes = 
    Enum.GetValues(typeof(NotificationMethodType))
    .Cast<NotificationMethodType>()
    .Aggregate ((current, value) => current | value);
```

This builds the `allType` value by OR'ing together all the individual values of the enum.

Answer (score 4):

A simple XOR will do the trick...

```
NotificationMethodType all = (NotificationMethodType.Email | NotificationMethodType.Fax | NotificationMethodType.Sms);
NotificationMethodType used = (NotificationMethodType.Email | NotificationMethodType.Fax);
NotificationMethodType unused = (all ^ used);
```

To make this a little cleaner, add the All value to your enum definition directly (set value to 7 obviously).  This way, you can add things to the enum later without breaking this code

Comment: fwiw, XOR (the ^ operators) and Lasse's 'and not' answer are mathematically the same thing.

Comment: Robert, thanks for that. Personally I find its easier to read `& ~`

Answer (score 1):

```
var notAssigned = Enum.GetValues(typeof(NotificationMethodType))
                      .Cast<NotificationMethodType>()
                      .Where(x => !types.HasFlag(x))
                      .Aggregate((a, x) => a | x);
```

Comment: waay less efficient than either of the 2 answers which use bitwise operators

Comment: @Robert: I can't deny that it's less efficient, but its suitability really depends on what the OP needs. Your own answer requires a separate `all` value to be kept in sync with the main enum - a maintenance nightmare if that enum ever changes! (And that's way more of a drawback, imo, than a supposed efficiency problem that will probably *never* be noticed in most situations. I'm obviously less free-and-easy with my downvoting than you are.)

Comment: agreed, All should be defined as part of the enum